# RSpec & Rails: Stub request.path for helper spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request

I have this method in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def home_link_class
  classes = ['navbar-brand']
  classes << 'active' if request.path == root_path
  classes
end
```

I want to test it like this:

```
describe '#home_link_class' do
  before  { allow(helper.request).to receive(:path).and_return '/some-path' }
  subject { home_link_class }

  it { should eq ['navbar-brand'] }
end
```

Sadly the stubbing doesn't seem to work, the `request` object in the helper itself is set to `nil`, even though in the spec it seems to be an `ActionController::TestRequest` object.

How do I make sure that `request` is available in the spec?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to stub the request itself as well as the return value of path. Define a test double for the request that stubs `path`:

```
describe '#home_link_class' do
  let(:request) { double('request', path: '/some-path') }

  before  { allow(helper).to receive(:request).and_return(request) }
  subject { home_link_class }

  it { should eq ['navbar-brand'] }
end
```